# Angular SSR With Subdomains

Tags: javascript, angular, express, server-side-rendering

I am building a project with 3 web applications (public, user, and store) and an API. Each web application has its own subdomain: `www.domain.com` for the public app, `user.domain.com` for the user app, and `(store-id)*.domain.com` for the store app. I want to use server-side rendering (SSR) for all of the web apps, so when a link is shared, a card with data from the page can be displayed.

I want to separate the API and user apps from each other. I want all of the web apps to access the api.domain.com subdomain to get the data they need. (should I do that?)

I quess that I will have to use `express-engine` to make requests to the `api.domain.com` subdomain, where there is an `Express` app that handles the requests.

Is this the correct approach to set up my project with multiple web apps and an API that are accessed through subdomains, and how can I implement SSR for each app?

This is how I want the project structure to be:

```
my-app/
├─ web/ - contains web-apps with ssr, thay all make requests to one api
│  ├─ user/
│  ├─ public/
│  ├─ store/
├─ api/
│  ├─ index.js - this is where all the requests handled from all the web apps
```